# MySQL Stored Procedure with Prepared Statement does not work

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getLastValueAutomaticShelter(IN fieldName varchar(30), position_number INT)
BEGIN
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM automatic_changes WHERE',fieldName,'IS NOT NULL AND P_id=?');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
SET @position_number=position_number;
EXECUTE stmt USING @position_number;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Then I am running it:

```
mysql> call getLastValueAutomaticShelter('current_level', 500)//
```

And getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT N
ULL AND P_id=?' at line 1
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some spaces in there:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM automatic_changes WHERE ',fieldName,' IS NOT NULL AND P_id=?');
/*                                                  right ^ here....and ^ here*/
```

Otherwise your final query might look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM automatic_changes WHEREcolumnameIS NOT NULL AND P_id='whatever';
```

You get the idea :)